# Routing guid coming up as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an hybrid application which is classic asp.net and MVC both. It is asp.net 4.5 and MVC 4.

**Problem:**
From the route, i can get to the action just fine but the guid is always coming up as null. Do you see any thing that i may be missing in my implementation? Problem is with SiteMyHome route.

**Route**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
        //Ignore calls to httphandlers
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            RouteConstants.SiteMyHome,
            RouteConstants.SiteMyHome + "/{guid}/{ccode}/{tab}",
            new { controller = ControllerNames.SiteRouter, action = ActionNames.SiteMyHome, ccode = UrlParameter.Optional, tab = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        //Set the default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult SiteMyHome(Guid? guid, string ccode, string tab)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

**Test**
/SiteMyHome/9c95eb0-d8fb-4176-9de0-5b99f8b914db/test/matched

When i debug my action, i get the following

```
guid = null
ccode = test
tab = matched
```

Why is guid getting passed as null here?

Now, when i change the action to **string guid** then i get its value just fine (image attached). I am confused...

```
public ActionResult SiteMyHome(string guid, string ccode, string tab)
```

[image]

Comment: As you've made Guid a nullable field it implies that this action parameter is optional. Hence you could try including "guid = UrlParameter.Optional" in the relevant MapRoute as I think this might fix the problem.

Comment: If i dont make it nullable then i get an error since null gets passed to the action. After the error i changed it to nullable field to check its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a guid issue. The guid that i was testing with is not a valid guid where as d04e9071-0cdf-4aa8-8f34-b316f9f3c466 is resulting in a valid guid.